# Ansible playbook returning : No hosts matched

Tags: ansible

I am new to Ansible.

I created a test playbook. When I try to run i always get  "No hosts matched". 
I have placed my ansible.cfg in the same directory where I have this ply book. 
Below are contents of files I have

**test-playbook.yml**

```
    ---
- name: Test file
  hosts: development
  sudo: yes
  sudo_user: root
  roles:
   - { role: copyFile, src: /home/rajesh.devan/Hello.txt, dest: /home/rajesh.devan/HelloWorld.txt }


 environment:
    TEMP: /home/rajesh.devan
```

**ansible.cfg:**

```
[defaults]
inventory = /home/rajesh.devan/ansible_test/inventory/hosts
```

**hosts:**

```
[development]
dXXXXX516.global.XXXX.com
```

When I run :

```
[root@dtraflocorh516 ansible_test]#  ansible test-playbook.yml No hosts matched
```

Please help!!

Thanks,

PS: I am new to Ansible so please be explicit

Comment: Now I end up getting this error .[root@dtraflocorh516 ansible_test]#  ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml
ERROR: provided hosts list is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ansible` CLI is for ad-hoc commands.
If you want to run a playbook, call `ansible-playbook test-playbook.yml`.

Comment: Don't forget to also use the -k and -K flags because you are using sudo and will need to provide a password, assuming your server is configured to prompt for a sudo password (which it hopefully is).